# Returning an array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, return

I'm working on an assignment in which I'm required to have a method return a pointer to an array of strings, read from a file.  The function works, but when I try to assign the returned pointer to a variable in the main function, I end up with an array of null values.  Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char **buildAnsArray(){

    FILE *in;
    int num, i;

    in = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    fscanf(in, "%d", &num);

    char ansArray[10][num];

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
        fscanf(in, "%s", ansArray[i]);
    }

    return ansArray;
};


main(){
    char **ansArray = buildAnsArray();
}
```

The input file (data.txt) that I'm working with begins with:

```
3
B
20
1101
```

ansArray (in buildAnsArray) correctly contains {'B', '20', '1101'}, but ansArray (in main) is empty.  I know I could just move everything to main and not worry about returning the pointer to the string array, but the assignment requires the buildAnsArray function. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String is not captured from return value in function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046538/string-is-not-captured-from-return-value-in-function-in-c)

Comment: Not 100% sure this is related to your problem, but if you want to return a pointer from a function you should allocate your array on the heap (using `malloc`). Right now you are creating your array on the stack, which means it can (and will) get cleaned up eventually after your function call

Comment: This has *many* duplicates in different forms, but ultimately it boils down to this: You're returning an address of an automatic variable (i.e. it no longer exists once your function returns, therefore invoking *undefined behavior*). Adding further logs to the fire, the resulting pointer-type isn't even compatible with your declared result type of the function (`char**` is **not** the same as `char[][N]`). If your compiler didn't warn you about *either*, you need to turn up your warning levels to be considerably more verbose.

Comment: Note that the semicolon after the final close brace of the function is actually an empty declaration.  Don't write semicolons where they aren't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char ansArray[10][num];
return ansArray;
```

is a temporary variable.  It is destroyed as soon as the function returns.

Do this:
...

```
char** ansArray = malloc(num * sizeof(char*));
for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
    char* item = malloc(10*sizeof(char));

    fscanf(in, "%s", item);
    ansArray[i] = item;

}
```

...
    return ansArray;

and then

```
main(){

    char **ansArray = buildAnsArray();
    printf("%s", ansArray[1]);
    free(ansArray);
}
```

Also, since the number of strings is allocated in the function, you need to return num also so the individual items in ansarray can be freed, which isn't shown above.

Comment: the question is tagged C, suggesting C++ code (`new` and `delete`) is not helpful

Comment: What exactly have you written? `new`? `delete`? This isn't C++ the author has posted, it's C

Comment: That did the trick!  I had tried malloc before, but I hadn't thought to malloc individual items and add them to an array.  Thank you very much!