# Returning an array of strings from a function in C

Tags: c, arrays

I was trying to create a function that takes a char** as a parameter and returns a char** type. The purpose of this function is to sort a list of strings alphabetically. I have this code and I can't figure out why my code doesn't work. I saw this answer "[Returning an array of strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516866/returning-an-array-of-strings-in-c)", but I still can't figure out why the following code crushes...

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** a_to_z_ordering (char**, int);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char** unordered;
    //char** ordered;

    unordered = malloc(50*150); //is it ok to use more space? (In case my max is what the numbers declare)
    //ordered = malloc(50*150); //should I declare like this?

    for(int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
        unordered[i] = malloc(150*sizeof(char));
    }

    //for(int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
    //  ordered[i] = malloc(150*sizeof(char));
    //}

    strcpy(unordered[0], "ba");
    strcpy(unordered[1], "ab");
    strcpy(unordered[2], "aa");

    printf("The list of strings without alphabetical ordering:\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("This is string %d: %s\n", i, unordered[i]);
    }

    //arrange strings to alphabetical ordering
    char** ordered = a_to_z_ordering(unordered, 3); //3 elements + \0?

    printf("\n\nThe list of strings WITH alphabetical ordering:\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("This is string %d: %s\n", i, ordered[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

char** a_to_z_ordering (char** arrayOfStrings, int arraySize) {
    char* tempString = malloc(150*sizeof(char));

    arrayOfStrings = malloc(50*150);
    for(int i = 0; i<arraySize; i++) {
        arrayOfStrings[i] = malloc(150*sizeof(char));
    }

    for(size_t i = 1; i < arraySize; i++) {
        for(size_t n = 1; n <arraySize; n++) {
            if(strcmp(arrayOfStrings[n-1], arrayOfStrings[n]) > 0) {
                strcpy(tempString, arrayOfStrings[n-1]);
                strcpy(arrayOfStrings[n-1], arrayOfStrings[n]);
                strcpy(arrayOfStrings[n], tempString);
            }
        }
    }
    return arrayOfStrings;
}
```

Comment: `unordered = malloc(50*150); ` totally wrong. You are allocating an array of 50 char pointers, the correct expression is `unordered = malloc(50*sizeof(char*)); `

Comment: You are tryong to sort an array of 50 strings but you have initialized only 3 array elements. Elements from 3 to 49 contain unpredictable garbage that may or may not be null-terminated strings.

Comment: @user3121023 You are right! Thank you! Why don't you write your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Why can't you just swap the values of the `char*`'s in your sorting procedure?

Comment: @IatropoulosGeorge do you have something against `qsort`? It is orders of magnitude faster than your manual sort and your `compare` function for `qsort` (the last parameter) can simply be written to sort ascending/descending, etc., however you choose. In your case, you are rewriting a complete sort routine where you would only need to write a compare function to use `qsort` (not to mention that `qsort` has been developed and validated with years of testing -- where your sort function may not be quite as -- proven, shall we say)

Comment: Remeber, You must always free after using malloc!